# How to make a large list to small list of lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

My list is of length 78. Each of this having some binary values in it.

```
 R=  [......[0.], [0.],
        [0.], [1.], ..... [0.], [0.], [0.],
        [0.],[0.],[0.], [0.], [0.], [0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Length of R is 78. I want to separate this list into smaller 13 subsist.

- The first 6 list --> **list1**
- The next 6 list --> **list2**
- ..and so on

How to make a large list to small list of lists?

Comment: The presence of `dtype=float32` suggests you're using `numpy`.  If that's the case, and you specifically only need to deal with a list of 78 items, you can use `R.reshape(-1, 6)` to give you a two-dimensional array, which can be used in a similar way to a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `R_1 = R[:6]` to get the first one, `R_2 = R[6:12]` for the second ...

To make it programatically, try:

```
M = 6
R_i = []  
for i in range(len(R)//M)):
    R_i.append(R[i*M:(i+1)*M)])
```

Then all your smaller lists will be accesible through `R_i`